# A way to display small text below an icon with onMouseOver

Tags: events, onmouseover, react-tsx

I'm using react and I want to make a onMouseOver in order to display a small text

`onMouseOver={(e) => { alert('Set to started'); }}`

I've tried this action but it makes a HTML alert on top. I just want a small text.

I cant seem to find something that displays it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert` is a function of `window` object. Its default behavior is to show a modal that prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed. You can read more here: [Window: alert() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

To achieve what you desire, you should create an element, like a `div` or a `p` and set style `display: none` or `display: block` for it, depending on a state, for example `[error, setError] = useState('')`.

By the way, with this approach, remember to implement `onMouseLeave` along with `onMouseOver`, because the state would not automatically reverts to its origin value.

Here's a working example for you. Hope it helps.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Test() {
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <h1
        onMouseOver={() => setError('[Your error message here]')}
        onMouseLeave={() => setError('')}
      >
        Hover me!
      </h1>
      <h4 style={{
        color: 'red',
        display: error === '' ? 'none' : 'block'
      }}>
        {error}
      </h4>
    </div>
  )
}
```